# Get value from select input in AJAX/PHP retrieved innerhtml for form submit

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm new to the AJAX thing, but seems fairly simple. I have a form page that has a select input, when the user selects a certain option, the AJAX populates an innerhtml div with the timeslot.php. The timeslot.php has another dynamically created select input with the options that are populated from a Mysql database. My problem is getting the value back to the form page so when the user clicks submit, that value (hidden input) is included in the submit. I figured it would be pretty straight forward, but what I have does not work. Any help with this would be appreciated.

HTML form:

```
<?php

$omitDay = 'Sunday'; //Sunday is a permanant day off from curbside service

  if ('17:00:00' <= date("H:i:s")){ //ADDED date("H:i:s", strtotime(time()))
    $start = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime(date("Y-m-d"))));
} else {
    $start = date("Y-m-d"); 
}

$end = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+6 day", strtotime(date("Y-m-d"))));

?>

<html>
<head>
<script>
function showUser(str) {
  if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  } else {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        var timeslotvalue = document.getElementByID("timeslot").value;
        alert(timeslotvalue);
      }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","timeslot.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<div style="clear:both; margin-bottom: 20px;">

<input type="hidden" name="timeslot"> Javascript value from Timeslot select </input>

<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)"><option value="">Select a Pickup Day</option>
<?php

$datediff = strtotime($end) - strtotime($start);
$datediff = floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
for($i = 0; $i < $datediff + 1; $i++){

    $todaysDate = date("l, F d", strtotime($start . '+' . $i . 'day'));
    $day = date('l', strtotime($start . '+' . $i . 'day'));

        if($day != $omitDay) {

            echo '<option value="' . strtotime($todaysDate) .'">'. $todaysDate . '</option>';

        }
} 

?>
</select>

</div>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint">Select goes here</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my php file with select input (I do not have the SQL database in this code, not the issue)

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

$startTime = time() + (60 * 60 * 4
);

$timeIncrements = array('08:15:00','08:20:00','08:25:00','08:30:00','08:35:00','08:40:00','08:45:00','08:50:00','08:55:00','09:00:00','09:05:00','09:10:00','09:15:00','09:20:00','09:25:00','09:30:00','09:35:00','09:40:00','09:45:00',
'09:50:00','09:55:00','10:00:00','10:05:00','10:10:00','10:15:00','10:20:00','10:25:00','10:30:00','10:35:00','10:40:00','10:45:00','10:50:00','10:55:00','11:00:00','11:05:00','11:10:00','11:15:00','11:20:00','11:25:00','11:30:00',
'11:35:00','11:40:00','11:45:00','11:50:00','11:55:00','13:00:00','13:05:00','13:10:00','13:15:00','13:20:00','13:25:00','13:30:00','13:35:00','13:40:00','13:45:00','13:50:00','13:55:00','14:00:00','14:05:00','14:10:00','14:15:00',
'14:20:00','14:25:00','14:30:00','14:35:00','14:40:00','14:45:00','14:50:00','14:55:00','15:00:00','15:05:00','15:10:00','15:15:00','15:20:00','15:25:00','15:30:00','15:35:00','15:40:00','15:45:00','15:50:00','15:55:00','16:00:00',
'16:05:00','16:10:00','16:15:00','16:20:00','16:25:00','16:30:00','16:35:00','16:40:00','16:45:00','16:50:00','16:55:00');

$omitTime = array('08:25:00'); // to be pulled from database as users select their timeslot and it's saved
$timeIncrements = array_diff( $timeIncrements, $omitTime ); // takes out the omitted times

$q = $_GET['q'] . '<br />';

// Database select here

echo '<select name="timeslot" id="timeslot"><option value="">Select a Pickup Time</option>';


foreach ($timeIncrements as $timeslot) {

    if ($startTime <= strtotime($timeslot)) {  //starttime = 0000000000 /timeslot = 00:00:00

    echo '<option value="' . date("h:i a", strtotime($timeslot)) .'">'. date("h:i a", strtotime($timeslot)) . '</option>';

    }

}

echo '</select>';

?>
```

Comment: Just use Javascript to insert the `<select name="timeslot"` etc (which you get back from timeslot.php) somewhere inside the `<form` tag (instead of into the "txtHint" area which is outside the form). Then whatever that user selects in that list will be posted back with the rest of the form when it's submitted. No need for an additional hidden field. (And anyway your code doesn't even attempt to write any value into the hidden field, so there's no question of "doesn't work", it simply "doesn't".)

Comment: ADyson, that was too simple. I had no idea that would be the case, I just wasted the last 24 hours trying how to figure out how to get that to work. I assumed that because the innerhtml div was empty even though it displays the select input, that it would ne return anything. I thank you so much for that solution.

Comment: " the innerhtml div was empty even though it displays the select input"...not really sure what you mean by that? If the select is there, then clearly it's not empty. But anyway glad you solved your issue.

Comment: If you look at the page code via view source, the div is empty.

Comment: Ah, that's because View Source is a static view of how the HTML document looked at the time the page was first loaded into the browser. If you use the Element inspector in your browser's Developer Tools, you can see changes to the HTML which take place as a result of Javascript actions.